# Suggestions for SharePoint event attendee management

Tags: workflow, list, events

I want to manage attendees attending a number of events in SharePoint.

The idea I have, and I believe IW site is the same, is to:

- Create a list for events - basic custom list.
- Create a list for registrations - custom list with lookup to event list and lookup to people.
- People then go to the registration list and "register" by adding an item.

It just feels this could be done better, but I have limited ideas.

Ideas I have:

- Custom register form which will be more simplified and can do one click registration.
- What I think would be nicer, would be have folders created in registration when an event is created and registrations are put in the folder for the event. Bit of custom workflow + custom register form could make this happen.

Anyone got comments or other ideas?

Comment: i want to create event management site.... can you please provide any site template for event management thanks

Comment: @shub: This really should be a new question. You can use the "Ask Question" button at the top.

Answer (score 4):

There are upgraded Fab40 templates for sharepoint 2010, one being the employee training template which is a self service event registration system.  Those can be found [here](http://www.techsolutions.net/Blog/tabid/65/EntryId/17/Fab-40-Templates-for-MOSS-2010.aspx).  The 2007 template had a few bugs with it and I'm not certain if they've been resolved in the 2010 version.  I've made extensive customizations to that template, so if you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Eric - I am using the employee training template and I want registration to close 7 days prior to class and also I want a list of those attendees that are registered emailed to a few people. I know I need to do a workflow... but I don't know how and I was wondering if you had any good ideas? Thanks!

Comment: There's some XSLT that needs to be modified on the register.aspx page to accommodate that.  It can be done as I've extended the registration window by 72 hours on one of our sites.  The second part might not be as easy.  You'll probably have to create a DVWP of the roster with query string filtering and send a link to the desired users.

Answer (score 2):

I have a suggestion. You could use incoming email for email RSVP. Set up an RSVP list per event with an email address you use as the reply to for the invite. Each reply would be added to the list as an RSVP.

Comment: I like the idea, would be great to have a single list and folders per event but it is a nice start!